# OpenLayers transform

Tags: openlayers

My script:

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/openlayers@4.4.2"></script>
  <script>
        var ETRS89Extent = [5.93, 34.76, 18.99, 47.1];
        proj4.defs('EPSG:6706', '+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs');

        var ETRS89proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'EPSG:6706',
            extent: ETRS89Extent
        });
        ol.proj.addProjection(ETRS89proj);
        var startResolution = ol.extent.getWidth(ETRS89Extent) / 1024;
        var resolutions = new Array(22);
        for (var i = 0, ii = resolutions.length; i < ii; ++i) {
            resolutions[i] = startResolution / Math.pow(2, i);
        }
        var tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
            extent: ETRS89Extent,
            resolutions: resolutions,
            tileSize: [1024, 1024]
        });
        alert(ol.proj.transform(ol.extent.getCenter(ETRS89Extent), ETRS89proj, 'EPSG:3857'));
    </script>
```

The result of alert is 1387040.8552841886,5002022.15162612

The same script with a newer version of openlayers

```
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  <script>
        var ETRS89Extent = [5.93, 34.76, 18.99, 47.1];
        proj4.defs('EPSG:6706', '+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs');

        var ETRS89proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'EPSG:6706',
            extent: ETRS89Extent
        });
        ol.proj.addProjection(ETRS89proj);
        var startResolution = ol.extent.getWidth(ETRS89Extent) / 1024;
        var resolutions = new Array(22);
        for (var i = 0, ii = resolutions.length; i < ii; ++i) {
            resolutions[i] = startResolution / Math.pow(2, i);
        }
        var tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
            extent: ETRS89Extent,
            resolutions: resolutions,
            tileSize: [1024, 1024]
        });
        alert(ol.proj.transform(ol.extent.getCenter(ETRS89Extent), ETRS89proj, 'EPSG:3857'));
    </script>
```

The result of alert is 12.459999999,40.93

Why do I get two different coordinates? Is the function ol.proj.transform correct?

Comment: You need to register proj4 by adding `ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);` after the `proj4.defs();` line https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/apidoc/module-ol_proj_proj4.html

Comment: Thanks! Now it's ok!